# Search is not auto listing the contents

Tags: magento-1.9, search

As far as a search field is concerned, when we search an item
eg: jewel , just after typing "j" in the field , it should provide all the 
results starting with "j"

but here the auto listing of items are not working ,

[image]

in the above image you can see that when 'y' is typed it provides 3

results but all those results provided are the already searched names.

Only the already searched names are shown in the result , it doesn't show

the complete products in the page starting with `y`

eg(below) : when a new item is searched , no related items are shown in the dropdown  [image]

I have indexed as well as removed the cache, Still the case is same.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: did u solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature, not a bug. This is how the search autosuggest works in Magento.
The suggestions are not products. They are previous search queries that produced at least one result.
If you type in a new search query, it will be stored and presented as a suggestion for the next similar search.

Comment: Hi marius ,                                                                                                                     The results that i have got when i tested in my system/browser is not shown when i tested in a different browser / system .For each browser / system the search results are different , they are providing the system stored data, magento related searching is not shown anywhere .